# Is there a safe way to execute code from users/clients in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, security, user-defined-functions

users/clients compile their C++ code to dynamic library(e.g. `libuser.so`) and upload to servers on Linux(x64).

Server process opens `libuser.so` and calls functions in it.

1. How to prevent server process core dump(and other errors) from **any errors** of `libuser.so`?
2. How to control the resources of `libuser.so` can access? (e.g. Memory, disk, and CPU)
3. Maybe there are some evil users/clients.

Comment: There's no way AFAIK.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ maybe google's native client is ok, but I want a lightweight solution.

Comment: I've definitely never tried anything like this, so this is just a thought... but would it be possible to spawn a process with a different set of privileges (I think windows allows you to spawn a process with a lower integrity level... not sure about linux) and then load the .so from that process?

Comment: On Linux, you could try a combination of cgroups and namespaces (perhaps via a ready-made library) for resource isolation.

Comment: @EOF is there a `hello world` doc for this usage?

Answer (score 3):

There is no 100% safe scenario, but usually it goes along following lines:

- Dedicate a special user for this kind of activity
- restrict everything for this user
- whenever libuser needs to be executed, spawn a new process as this special user, chroot into sandbox and pray :

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SergeyA answer I would recommend to execute code on a virtual machine using `vmware` or `virtualbox` or something like that. You probably can create a new virtual machine per user, per session (that would be probably too expensive) etc, share some path, copy libuser.so there and use RPC to make a call and get results back.

Using https://www.docker.com/ instead of vmware etc will probably simplify creating new virtual machine and make it cheaper.